# View top 5 most appearances - python - sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, e-commerce

I want to find my top 5 customers by their username from my database:

The database code is:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "OrderHistory" (
    `Username`  TEXT,
    `ProductID` TEXT,
    `Category`  INTEGER,
    `Date`  TEXT,
    `Qty`   INTEGER,
    `ItemHistory`   TEXT,
    `TotalPrice`    INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO `OrderHistory` (Username,ProductID,Category,Date,Qty,ItemHistory,TotalPrice) VALUES 
     ('saqib','1',7,'2017-01-12',2,'Cookie',4),
     ('saqib','1',7,'2017-01-12',10,'Cookie',20),
     ('saqib','1',7,'2017-01-13',12,'Cookie',24),
     ('saqib','1',7,'2017-01-13',8,'Cookie',16),
     ('malik','1',7,'2017-01-13',5,'Cookie',10),
     ('malik','1',7,'2017-01-13',4,'Cookie',8),
     ('dex','1',7,'2017-01-13',7,'Cookie',14),
     ('olly','1',7,'2017-01-13',3,'Cookie',6),
     ('matt','1',7,'2017-01-13',9,'Cookie',18);
    COMMIT;
```

i want to find out which customers buy the most products

this is in simple python and sqlite no framework in use

Comment: This actually looks like a SQL question best solved using a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Anonimista and how do you do that, i dont have a clue how you do that can you write the code to explain if you don't mind

Comment: BTW, using backticks for quoting identifiers is a MySQL-ism that SQLite supports for compatibility, using them outside of MySQL is a bad habit that you don't want to develop, use double quotes instead as that's the standard.

Comment: On my phone right now, sorry.

Comment: something like `SELECT username, sum(Qty) AS products_number GROUP BY username ORDER BY products_number DESC, username ASC LIMIT 5`

Comment: @furas where did you get the product_number from

Comment: I get `sum(Qty)` and assign new name (alias) `products_number` so later I can use this name instead of `sum(Qty)`. But this alias may not work in all elements of SQL - so it may not works sometimes.

Comment: @furas this is the code i used: cursor.execute("SELECT a.* FROM OrderHistory a WHERE (Username, sum(Qty) AS products_number GROUP BY Username ORDER BY products_number DESC, Username ASC LIMIT 5)")

Comment: @furas but it gives me this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: you can use `AS` only in `SELECT` before `FROM` - it is time to learn SQL.

Comment: BTW: you have `WHERE (....)` and inside `()` you have `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` - but it is not correct in SQL.

Comment: @furas so what would be the right query to fetch the data

Comment: @furas so how can i fix this query? BTW followed you on twitter

Comment: try my query from previous comment - I only forgot `FROM OrderHistory` before `GROUP BY`. I couldn't test it but it can work.

Comment: @furas thanks buddy, you have helped me alot!!

Comment: See your database and query on `SQL fiddle`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f6da2/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Username, sum(Qty) AS ProductsNumber 
FROM OrderHistory
GROUP BY Username 
ORDER BY ProductsNumber DESC, Username ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

You can test it on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f6da2/1